Encoder convolutional model fails to be trained on 3 channel images
I have created this encoder convolutional model for anomaly detection purposes:
def autoencoder(input_img):     
#encoder     
conv1 = tf.keras.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)      
conv1 = tf.keras.BatchNormalization()(conv1)     
conv1 = tf.keras.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)     
conv1 = tf.keras.BatchNormalization()(conv1)     pool1 = tf.keras.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)      
conv2 = tf.keras.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)      
conv2 = tf.keras.BatchNormalization()(conv2)     
conv2 = tf.keras.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)     
conv2 = tf.keras.BatchNormalization()(conv2)    
pool2 = tf.keras.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)     
conv3 = tf.keras.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)      
conv3 = tf.keras.BatchNormalization()(conv3)     
conv3 = tf.keras.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)    
conv3 = tf.keras.BatchNormalization()(conv3)     
#decoder     
conv4 = tf.keras.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)      
conv4 = tf.keras.BatchNormalization()(conv4)     
conv4 = tf.keras.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)    
conv4 = tf.keras.BatchNormalization()(conv4)     up1 = tf.keras.UpSampling2D((2,2))(conv4)     conv5 = tf.keras.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up1)      
conv5 = tf.keras.BatchNormalization()(conv5)     
conv5 = tf.keras.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)    
conv5 = tf.keras.BatchNormalization()(conv5)     up2 = tf.keras.UpSampling2D((2,2),data_format="channels_last")(conv5)     
decoded = tf.keras.Conv2D(1,(3, 3),activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(up2)      
return decoded

In the last Conv2D layer, when I set the filter size from 1 to 3 in order to train the model on rgb=3 channeled images, it throws error of shape mismatch:[32],[32,224,224,3]
I have built my dataset using this pipeline:
   # create dataset of normal cases
   import pandas as pd
   import tensorflow as tf
   import math
   batch_size = 32
   path_normal=image_data_normal['path'].values
   labels_normal=image_data_normal['label'].values`
   # Function to load and preprocess images
  def load_and_preprocess_image(path_normal):
     # Load the image
     image_normal = tf.io.read_file(path_normal,labels_normal)
     image_normal = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_normal, channels=3)  # Adjust channels as needed
     image_normal = tf.image.resize(image_normal,size= [224, 224])  # Resize to desired     dimensions
     image_normal = image_normal / 255.0  # Normalize to [0, 1]
     return image_normal,labels_normal

 # Create a TensorFlow dataset from the DataFrame
 dataset_normal = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_data_normal['path'].values,
                                                     image_data_normal['label'].values))
 print(len(dataset_normal))
 # Map the preprocessing function to the dataset
 dataset_normal = dataset_normal.map(load_and_preprocess_image)
 print(len(dataset_normal))
 # Shuffle the dataset
 dataset_normal = dataset_normal.shuffle(buffer_size=len(image_data))
 dataset_normal = dataset_normal.batch(batch_size)
 print(len(dataset_normal))
 # Split the dataset into training and validation sets
 train_size_normal=math.floor((len(dataset_normal)*0.8))
 train_dataset_normal = dataset_normal.take(train_size_normal)
 val_dataset_normal = dataset_normal.skip(train_size_normal)
 print(len(train_dataset_normal))
 print(len(val_dataset_normal))`

I have tried several things:
1.when i try on filter size of the last conv2D layer on 1 everything is fine until I want to measure difference between predicted and ground truth image's mean absolute error
2.I have also tried different Activations like linear and ... for the last layer
3.When i create my dataset without labels in order to resolve the shape mismatch error, it throws error of None can't be supported , however my dataset has been created correctly and the directories and shapes are as the input for the encoder model
It is necessary to state that i am using google colab env
